# Excluding devices in media queries

Tags: css, ipad, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to exclude iPads from using my CSS styling for desktop views on my website. I built my site mobile-first, so the desktop styles are in a media query.

While messing around with my code I tried this:

```
/*mobile and default styles (the styles I want the iPads to use)*/


@media (min-width: 750px;),
@media (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) /*iPad resolution*/ { 

/*desktop styles (the styles I don't want the iPad to use)*/
/*in this code, these styles are currently being ignored by iPads*/

}
```

I don't think this is valid code but it works correctly in every browser and device I have tested.

It has to do with having two `@media` lines on one media query. The second set of parameters are somehow excluded from the query, but I don't understand why. Without the second `@media` then it works like an `or` operator and the desktop styling will show up on an iPad.

I have tried nesting media queries, which doesn't seem to work, and I have tried using `not`, but the first line will still be true and thus it work work either.

I haven't found any information about **using `@media` twice** in a statement and having it somehow exclude the second media query, could someone explain the correct way to do this, or at least explain why this works?

Comment: It seems like the iPad, not being fully up-to-date, Is just parsing my CSS differently and therefore this is just some broken code that I should not attempt to use. I will just make a separate media query for my iPad styling and deal with the extra code.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant - yet incorrect syntax according to VS12.
Can be seen working here http://www.stilborg.com on iPad.